# D3 map shifts after rendering new paragraph below

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 map that allows me to create text paragraphs below the map when countries in blue are clicked.

The map initially looks like this: [image: centered world map]
When clicking the blue countries, a text paragraph is generated which says a blurb of text below.
The issue is the map shifts to the far left side when the text paragraph is rendered as shown here: [image: Map shifted] NOTE: you can't see the shift unless you open it in a new tab

link to codesandbox dev environment:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/d3-world-map-shifts-after-rendering-paragraph-przqvp?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.jsx&embed=1

JSX:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef,useState} from "react"; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import mapdata from "./Components/data.csv";

let visitedCountries = ["USA","Canada","Ireland","Egypt","Czech Republic","Germany","France","Greece","Iceland","Italy","Japan","Lao People's Democratic Republic","Mexico","Norway","Poland","Thailand"];
function RecieveCountry(props) {
    let contains = visitedCountries.includes(props.name);
    if(contains){
        return(
            <div >
                    <p className = "Text">
                    Smallest directly families surprise honoured am an. Speaking replying mistress him numerous she returned feelings may day. Evening way luckily son exposed get general greatly. Zealously prevailed be arranging do. Set arranging too dejection september happiness. Understood instrument or do connection no appearance do invitation. Dried quick round it or order. Add past see west felt did any. Say out noise you taste merry plate you share. My resolve arrived is we chamber be removal.

                    On on produce colonel pointed. Just four sold need over how any. In to september suspicion determine he prevailed admitting. On adapted an as affixed limited on. Giving cousin warmly things no spring mr be abroad. Relation breeding be as repeated strictly followed margaret. One gravity son brought shyness waiting regular led ham.

                    </p>
            </div>
        );
    }else{
        return(
            <div >
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const WorldMap = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const ref2 = useRef();
  const [Country, setCountry] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    const width = 900;
    const height = 900;
    
    const svg = d3
      .select(ref.current)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height",height)

    // Map and projection
    const path = d3.geoPath();
    const projection = d3.geoMercator()

    .center([0,20])
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
  
  // Data and color scale
  const data = new Map();
  const colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,1])
  .range(["grey","blue"]);
  
  // Load external data and boot
  Promise.all([
  d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson"),
  d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world_population.csv", function(d) {
      data.set(d.code, +d.visited)
  })]).then(function(loadData){
      let topo = loadData[0]
  
      let mouseOver = function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".Country")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .5)
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke", "black")
    }
  
    let mouseLeave = function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".Country")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .8)
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("stroke", "transparent")
    }

    let mouseClick = function (event, d) {
            d3.selectAll(".Country")
              .transition()
              .duration(200)
              .style("opacity", 0.8);
            d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(200)
              .style("stroke", "transparent");
              setCountry(d.properties.name);
              console.log(d.properties.name);
              
          };
    
    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topo.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
        // draw each country
        .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
          .projection(projection)
        )
        // set the color of each country
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
          d.total = data.get(d.id) || 0;
          return colorScale(d.total);
        })
        .style("stroke", "transparent")
        .attr("class", function(d){ return "Country" } )
        .style("opacity", .8)
        .on("mouseover", mouseOver )
        .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave )
        .on("click", mouseClick); // Attach the mouseClick function
  
  });
  }, [Country]);
  
  return <div className = "worldTravel">
    <div><svg width={900} height={900} id="WorldMap" ref={ref} /></div>
    <div><RecieveCountry name = {Country} ref = {ref2}/></div>
    </div>;
};

function App() {
    return (
      <div className ="worldTravel">
      <WorldMap />
      </div>
    );
  }

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <App/>
);
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.worldTravel{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
}

.Text{
  color:black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do that in the codesandbox...

Comment: It isn't really noticeable unless you pop it out in a new tab which is something I should have mentioned

Comment: You seem to want your app to be contained in a 900px container but haven't set this max-width on it. Here's [a fixed clone of your app](https://gf8rk4-3000.csb.app/), with a couple more fixes (no more `<svg />` nesting; and no longer generating a new clone of the map every time the country is changed).

Comment: You might want to start looking into libraries like Bootstrap or Tailwind CSS, which make it easier to control the behavior of the layout using utility classes, without the need to understand all of the CSS involved. From what you've shown so far, you're not yet at the level where you could come up with production ready CSS solutions that would work in any browser, on any device.